# How to join multiple dataframes (reduce function), rename columns to original data frame names?

Tags: python, pandas, functools

I have 12 dataframes (july_df, aug_df.........june_df)

They all share the same column names and I'd like to merge them joining on the first column, "MINISTRY", and rename all the columns with the name of the df.

For example, output could look like:

```
Ministry item_jul item_aug.......item_jun item2_jul item2_aug.....item2jun
xyz          1       10            12        11        22           11
abc
```

Comment: Can you post a snippet of one of the individual dataframes?

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```py
import pandas as pd

def get_df_name(df):
    name = [x for x in globals() if globals()[x] is df][0]
    return name

# Toy dataframes
june = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "ministry": ["abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl"],
        "item": [1, 2, 3, 4],
        "item2": [5, 6, 7, 8],
        "item3": [9, 10, 11, 12],
    }
)
july = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "ministry": ["abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl"],
        "item": [13, 14, 15, 16],
        "item2": [17, 18, 19, 20],
        "item3": [21, 22, 23, 24],
    }
)
august = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "ministry": ["abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl"],
        "item": [25, 26, 27, 28],
        "item2": [29, 30, 31, 32],
        "item3": [33, 34, 35, 36],
    }
)

dfs = [june, july, august]

# Merge dataframes on "ministry" after renaming columns
merged_dfs = dfs[0]
merged_dfs.columns = [
    f"{col}_{get_df_name(merged_dfs)}" if col != "ministry" else col
    for col in merged_dfs.columns
]

for df in dfs[1:]:
    df.columns = [
        f"{col}_{get_df_name(df)}" if col != "ministry" else col for col in df.columns
    ]
    merged_dfs = merged_dfs.merge(df, on="ministry")

print(merged_dfs)
# Outputs
  ministry  item_june  item2_june  ...  item_august  item2_august  item3_august
0      abc          1           5  ...           25            29            33
1      def          2           6  ...           26            30            34
2      ghi          3           7  ...           27            31            35
3      jkl          4           8  ...           28            32            36
```